# Read NFC tag written with NFC Tools

Tags: android, nfc

I followed this tutorial:
https://www.codexpedia.com/android/android-nfc-read-and-write-example/
If I use  
I can read and write the tags, if I use 
when I try to read a NFC written with NFC tools, android starts trigger but not my app. It is possibile to read NFC tags written with other apps?
thanks

Comment: Could you make your question clearer?

Comment: android app nfc tools can read/write tags. With the app I wrote I hope to read that tag (written with nfc tools) but, instead of reading the tag, seems that my app not recognize the tag and starts the default trigger (app?) that says that an nfc tag is detected. Im doig wrong with my app(?), what can be the reason that my app not start and read that tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a NFC service running in the background. When tag is detected it processes that event. It identifies the type of Tag and then creates an intent accordingly. There can be more than one application in Android device that are interested to process the tag. The tag dispatch system of the NFC Service decides the application to be launched.

In order to let NFC service know that your app is interested, your app should declare an intent filter with intent's action among the following: ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED, ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED, ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED.

Note that filtering for TECH_DISCOVERED intent needs an additional xml file that has one or more  elements. All the listed techs in it should be supported by tag for a match. This file name should be specified in intent-filter for tech.

Refer to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/nfc#dispatching for complete details.

Comment: so it is possibile to know what kind of event is fired by NFC tools app, and read what is written?

Comment: Yes, with your app, you can read the content on the tag written by the NFC Tools app. Just add intent filters, permissions in your app's manifest as detailed in the developer doc and see.

Comment: I'm able to write an empty tag and read it, but not able to read tag written with other app...private void buildTagViews(NdefMessage[] msgs) {
        if (msgs == null || msgs.length == 0) return;

        String text = "";
//        String tagId = new String(msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getType());
        byte[] payload = msgs[0].getRecords()[0].getPayload();
    give me null pointer exception. but the tag is written

Comment: Check what is there on tag with a standard app. Debug which line and which dereferencing is giving exception

Comment: what can I use as standard app?

Comment: NXP TagInfo is a great standard app to see the content